# Is there a clean way to add a logger to the global namespace in a Node server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In the top-level of each route handler in my (very small) server (I'm using the library `micro`, which seems to mimic a lot of `Express`), I instantiate a `logger` that sends logs to `elasticsearch`. By passing a `name` to the logger constructor, the logger appends that name to all logs it produces.

The hierarchy looks something like this:

```
router
  -routeA:
    global._logger = _logger(name: 'routeA')
  -routeB:
    global._logger = _logger(name: 'routeB')
```

My question is: if the server is handling multiple concurrent requests, will the `global._logger` be overwritten with each new route handler instantiation?

If so, is there a cleaner way to attach my `logger` to the global scope, vice passing it to every function I call?

Another option I thought of is to make `_logger` an object, with a `key` for each route, keyed on `req.url`. eg

```
_logger = {
  '/routeA': _logger(name: 'routeA'),
  '/routeB': _logger(name: 'routeB')
}
```

But this feels a little messy.

Comment: Are you *assigning* or *calling* `global._logger`? It's not clear from your pseudocode, and we can't tell whether it will overwrite anything or create multiple instances.

Comment: @Bergi I'm assigning in the top of each `route handler`, and then calling within the `route`. I clarified the pseudocode in the post, thanks.

Comment: Yes, in that case concurrent requests might overwrite each other. Why have a global variable at all when each logger should be local to the respective route?

Comment: thanks @Bergi. frankly my main motivation is just to avoid passing the `logger` down through each function.

Comment: But if the functions don't know from which route they were called, you really cannot work around that. The only other approach that comes to my mind is to collect the log from every function as part of its result (return value), and then add the route descriptor to those before actually writing them down.